# I wrote a program using ENTER to stop the program but it isn't working

Tags: c

I wrote this program to read a small amount of Spanish and English words from a file and prompt for an English word and get the Spanish translation. To stop the program they must press enter only. The program doesn't stop however, it just keeps waiting for another word. This is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE*in=fopen("input.txt","r");
    char English[9][20],Spanish[9][20],word[20];
    int find(char[],char[][20]);
    for(int j=0; j<=8;j++)
        fscanf(in,"%s",English[j]);
    for(int r=0;r<=8;r++)
        fscanf(in,"%s",Spanish[r]);
    printf("type some English word to stop press enter only\n");
    scanf("%s",word);
    while(strcmp(word,"")!=0){
    int t=find(word,English);
    printf("the Spanish word for %s is %s\n",word,Spanish[t]);
    printf("type some english word to stop press enter only\n");
    scanf("%s",word);}
    fclose(in);

}

int find(char word[],char English[][20]){
    for(int j=0;j<=8;j++)
        if(strcmp(English[j],word)==0) return j;
}
```

I thought pressing ENTER would save the empty string "" in the array word and the program would stop. This is the code for that.

```
while(strcmp(word,"")!=0)
```

I'm really new to coding, I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: `%s` can never read an empty string. It always waits for you to type a word.

Comment: If you want to read lines instead of words, use `fgets()`.

Comment: If you expected an empty string to stop it, why put it in a `while` loop? The loop could never repeat. If I type "hello" and then hit enter, the second `scanf` would read the enter and return an empty string, ending the program. For your program to work as expected, `scanf` has to both skip the enter and read the enter, which is not possible.

Comment: I used your suggestion and used fgets instead of %s. It worked thanks.

Comment: @learningtocode, to direct a message to a user you need to ping the username, like I did in this message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, just make the character q for quit:

```
  while(strcmp(word,"q")!=0){
        int t=find(word,English);
        printf("the Spanish word for %s is %s\n",word,Spanish[t]);
        printf("type some english word to stop press enter only\n");
        scanf("%s",word);
    }
    printf("\nExiting...\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

"New to coding" and "confused by scanf" is a universal truth.  Seriously, do *not* use scanf at all until you understand the language well enough to realize that you do not really ever need it.  That said, you can do:

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char word[1024];
        char c;
        int rc;
        while( ( rc = scanf("%1023[^\n]%c", word, &c)) == 2 ) {
                printf("word = %s\n", word);
        }
        return 0;
}
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n\nignored\n' | ./a.out
word = foo
word = bar
```

The format string matches everything up to a newline and stores it in `word`, and then consumes the newline with `%c`. (You could also use `%*c` and not provide a variable to be assigned.) When there are two adjacent newlines in the input stream, the first conversion specifier fails to match the second newline and the loop terminates.  Note that this will fail if any line of input exceeds 1023 chars.  Two general rules here: 1) `%s` cares about whitespace, and if you want to handle whitespace specially you should use `%[` insteead of `%s`, and 2) always, always, always check the value returned by scanf.  If you ever call scanf and it is not in an if condition or a loop control or the right hand side of an assignment, it is an error.